# Animation with framer motion layouts not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, animation, framer-motion

I have an image gallery with a filtering function. I want to animate the shifting of the images when they get filtered. I read online about using framer motion's layout feature. I saw examples emulating exactly what I want to do like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyg5Lpl6AiM). When I set it up in my workspace it does not work, it does weird stretch animations and looks horrible. I created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-waterfall-rdl2uk?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the issue. I would like to fix the animation so the tiles re-order properly. Any help would be appreciated thanks!